# gdalwarp output shifted 15 KM

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

This is similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186491/gdalwarp-causing-shift-in-pixels) regarding shifts in raster output, but the difference I'm experiencing is fairly large-- the output raster is shifted 15 KM to the south. Here's an image:

[image: Raster shift]

When viewed in ArcGIS, the original raster (green) claims to be in spatial reference GCS_Greenwich. When the properties of this coordinate system (Angular Unit, Prime Meridian, Semimajor Axis, Semiminor Axis, Inverse Flattening) are compared to WGS84, they are identical.

As such, I used the EPSG for wgs84 when to project the raster to web mercator:

`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 input.tif output.tif`

I'm using GDAL 2.1.0 dev. Is the coordinate system the issue?

Update: using esri's CopyRaster_management function and selecting WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere as the output coordinate system worked perfectly. I'd prefer to stick to GDAL however, because this will be running on a Linux server without arcpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A latitude shift of 15 km is a typical error with EPSG:3857 Web Mercator and Arcgis vs GDAL reprojection. The reason is Googles strange projection invention with ellipsoid and sphere calculation.

Try to avoid EPSG:3857 (you can use UTM instead), or do everything in Arcgis **or** GDAL, but not between both.

Comment: got it. I'm getting my data from another source-- should use whatever tool they are using (ArcGIS or GDAL) to be sure that the output is correct?

Comment: Also is there no way to correct for this using exclusively GDAL?

Comment: Exclusively means that you view the result only in GDAL based software, and not Arcgis.

Comment: I'm tiling the result using mapnik, then viewing in cartoDB. The output is displayed over an imagery basemap; I'll check the GDAL-projected raster against the imagery to see if it looks correct.

Comment: You could open the file in QGIS, and compare it against Openstreetmap background in the same CRS. It runs perfectly on Linux and WIndows, and once you get used to it you won't miss Arcgis anymore. BTW gdal2tiles can do the tiling too, mapnik also runs on Windows, and QGIS can display self-rendered tiles without a server.

Comment: Just checked plugged the tiles into a webmap and they match the imagery exactly-- thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @charlie Use esri style geotiff keys with `-co "GEOTIFF_KEYS_FLAVOR=ESRI_PE"` to work around the offset issue. See documentation at http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html.

Comment: @BrianBunker this looks great-- had no idea this existed. Thank you!