# How to fix SRTM half-pixel shift with GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, srtm, pixel

The SRTM data has an half-pixel shift (I assume that’s what is described [in the last FAQ](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/faq/), and that GeoServer uses pixel corner origin ?  I couldn’t find this information).

Despite this shift being apparently widely known, I couldn’t find directions on the best way to correct and publish these data in GeoServer.

I can think of two options :

- [reprocessing the data files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331405/159691) before importing them ;
- [defining a custom coordinate operation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#define-a-custom-coordinate-operation) in GeoServer.

What is the recommended option ?  I guess the answer depends on the frequency of the requests to the server (the former option being preferred for high frequency requests to lighten the server computation needs), but maybe I am missing a third option ?

Data are loaded into GeoServer through ImageMosaic plugin, and here is what `gdal_info` has to say about the `.tif` files :

```
$ gdalinfo srtm_38_03.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: srtm_38_03.tif
       srtm_38_03.tfw
Size is 6000, 6000
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (5.000000000000000,50.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333333)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   5.0000000,  50.0000000) (  5d 0' 0.00"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (   5.0000000,  45.0000000) (  5d 0' 0.00"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right (  10.0000000,  50.0000000) ( 10d 0' 0.00"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (  10.0000000,  45.0000000) ( 10d 0' 0.00"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      (   7.5000000,  47.5000000) (  7d30' 0.00"E, 47d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=6000x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

And the `.twf` file :

```
$ cat srtm_38_03.tfw 
            0.0008333333
            0.0000000000
            0.0000000000
           -0.0008333333
            5.0004166667
           49.9995833333
```

Comment: How are you adding the data to GeoServer tiff or ascii grid? what does gdalinfo say the pixel origin is?

Comment: can you add the contents of the tfw file

Comment: I thought that GeoServer would work from that info and give the correct answer but if you are sure you are seeing a half pixel offset, the quick and dirty fix is to edit the tfw file to use 5 and 50 on the bottom two lines

Comment: can you generate a small test dataset that shows the problem and submit a ticket

Comment: Could it be due to the ImageMosaic plugin then ?  Modifying the tfw files doesn’t seem to improve anything (even after deleting the ImageMosaic generated files).

Comment: You'd need to fire up a debugger to see exactly what's going on, and coverages aren't really my area of expertise.

Comment: How do you know that there is a half pixel shift? The center of the top-left pixel should be at `5.0004166667 49.9995833333`. Is it not there?

Comment: @user30184 It is indeed at this position, however according to the FAQ linked in the question (which actually uses this very pixel example) it should be at (50,5) — and I can *see* the shift with regard to other data, e.g. OSM.

Comment: Then the .tfw is wrong. But if fixing it as Ian Turton suggested did not correct the situation then I guess that DEM files are also georeferenced with GeoTIFF tags and they are also wrong. The issue seems to be in the data, not in GeoServer. I would suggest to contact the data provider. If you want to fix the wrong georeferencing of GeoTIFFs yourself there are a few alternatives.